# Concise way to draw multiple curves on one plot in R

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting

I have 6 functions which vary only slightly whose curve I want to be plotted on the same graph:

```
myfun1=function(x){y=x/(1-0.01*(1-x))}
myfun2=function(x){y=x/(1-0.05*(1-x))}
myfun3=function(x){y=x/(1-0.1*(1-x))}
myfun4=function(x){y=x/(1-0.2*(1-x))}
myfun5=function(x){y=x/(1-0.3*(1-x))}
myfun6=function(x){y=x/(1-0.5*(1-x))}

plot(myfun1, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
plot(myfun2, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), add=TRUE)
plot(myfun3, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), add=TRUE)
plot(myfun4, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), add=TRUE)
plot(myfun5, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), add=TRUE)
plot(myfun6, 0, 10, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), add=TRUE)
```

This gives me a plot as I would like with 6 curves. However, is there a more simple way of doing this that is only a few lines long? The only thing that is changing is the constant 0.01,0.05,... etc.

I would also like some kind of legend to indicate which curve is which so ideally the method would allow me to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use a function that returns a function like this:

```
f <- function(p) return(function(x){y=x/(1-p*(1-x))})
plot(0, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), type = "n")
for (x in c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5))
  plot(f(x), from = 0, to = 10, add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks @lukeA. I have tried `plot(f(x), from = 0, to = 10, add = TRUE,     col=c("yellow","green","blue","purple","red","orange")` to make the lines different colours but this just makes all the lines yellow. Any ideas how to make them all different colours?

Comment: One way to use different colours: `for (x in cols <- c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5)) plot(f(x), from = 0, to = 10, add = TRUE, col = which(x == cols))`.

Comment: Multiple calls to `plot(..., add=TRUE)` is rather ugly. Suggest using a single `plot` and then multiple calls to `curve` or `lines`

Comment: @BondedDust imo `for (z in c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5)) curve(f(z)(x), 0, 10, add = TRUE)` doesn't look that much better. Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: I do think it's better because it uses the existing xlim and ylim values on the graphical device.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be drastically improved, by creating a function generator. I also use `ggplot2` instead of base `plot` for a nicer visualization (totally subjective), and adding legends depending on the function.

```
param    = list(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5)
func_gen = function(u) function(x) x/(1-u*(1-x))
x        = seq(0,10,by=0.2)

library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)

df = ldply(param, function(u) data.frame(x=x, y=func_gen(u)(x), variable=as.character(u)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable)) + geom_point()
```

[image]